# iPhone - adding a CGPath to a NSMutableArray... how?

Tags: iphone

When I need to add a integer to an array I use

```
[myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:myInt]];
```

but what about CGPaths? How do I add them to the array?

I need something like

```
"[NSValue valueWithCGPath:myPath]"... ???!!!
```

any clues? thanks

Comment: You might want to have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240481/how-to-store-cggradientref-in-nsmutablearray

Comment: this is brilliant, thanks. It will serve for other stuff I am doing, but for this case it is crashing, because after adding the object to the array I archive it. As CGPaths are CFType, the archiving crashes... but anyway, as I said, it will serve for other purposes in the same app. Thanks!!!!! +1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way if you can target iOS 3.2 or higher is to wrap the `CGPathRef` in a `UIBezierPath`:

```
[myArray addObject:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:myPath]];
```

If you need to support earlier iOS versions, you can use a `CFArray` instead of `NSArray` because `CGPath` derives from `CFType`.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that but my problem is this: after adding all paths to the array, using the code you posted, I archive it using NSKeyedArchiver. When I try to unarchive that, it crashes. Is there a way to convert the path to another thing (instead of a UIBezierPath) and then store it on the array? I am just building this array for archival purposes.

Comment: Are you sure the archive actually produces anything?  You should probably post a separate question, how to archive and restore a UIBezierPath.  You may have to store the points and path metadata manually.

Comment: Kendall - **[here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400284/iphone-storing-and-retrieving-a-uibezierpath-with-nskeyedarchiver-crashing)** without any working solution. Yes, the archive is storing the data and the bezier data is loading successfully to NSData variable when unarchiving, but when I try to decode the data and produce a UIBezierPath, it crashes.